# There is an issue with my function that I can't seem to fix. For now, it says Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at joinslots

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, error-handling

The function I'm using is

```
function joinslots(freeTimings){
    joined=[];
    if(freeTimings.length==1){
        joined.push(freeTimings);
}
    if(freeTimings.length>1){
        for(i=0;i<=freeTimings.length;){
        //console.log(freeTimings[i]);
        time0=freeTimings[i].split("-");
        first0=time0[0];
        last0=time0[1];
        time1=freeTimings[i+1].split("-");
        first1=time1[0];
        last1=time1[1];
        if(last0==first1){
            newfirst=first0;
            newlast=last1;
            newtime = newfirst+"-"+newlast;
            joined.push(newtime);
            if(i+2<freeTimings.length){
            time2=freeTimings[i+2]
            first2=time2[0];
            last2=time2[1];
            if(first2==last1){
                 i=i+2;
            }
            else i++;
            }
            else i+=2;
        }
        else{
            joined.push(freeTimings[i]);
            i++;
        }  
        if(i==freeTimings.length-1){
            joined.push(freeTimings[i-1]);
            break;
        }      

    }

    }
    return joined;    



}
```

The input to this function is 30 minute slots of time and it should return one hour joined slots wherever possible.
Every time i fix an error, it throws another one which makes me think there is an underlying problem here that i can't figure out, apart from maybe the array going out of bounds for which I have kept an if statement.

For example, the input is

```
freeTimings=["8:00-8:30","8:30-9:00","9:00-9:30","12:00-12:30","12:30-13:00","13:00-13:30","13:30-14:00","14-14:30","15:30-16:00","16:00-16:30","17:30-18:00"]
```

the returned value must be

```
joined=["8:00-9:00","9:00-9:30","12:00-13:00","13:00-14:00","14:00-14:30","15:30-16:30","17:30-18:00"]
```

So any help with with fixing my function would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write method `slotMerge` to check whether two time strings can be merged. if it can merge return the merged slot otherwise return empty string.

With this method, Go thru the array and pushing the merged or unmerged slots into output array.

How this helps.

```js
const freeTimings = [
  "8:00-8:30",
  "8:30-9:00",
  "9:00-9:30",
  "12:00-12:30",
  "12:30-13:00",
  "13:00-13:30",
  "13:30-14:00",
  "14-14:30",
  "15:30-16:00",
  "16:00-16:30",
  "17:30-18:00"
];

const joinSlots = data => {
  const slotMerge = (str1, str2) => {
    const [start1, end1] = str1.split("-");
    const [start2, end2] = str2.split("-");
    return end1 === start2 ? `${start1}-${end2}` : "";
  };
  const output = [];
  let prev = data[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const curr = data[i];
    const mer = slotMerge(prev, curr);
    if (mer) {
      output.push(mer);
      prev = i + 1 < data.length ? data[i + 1] : undefined;
      i += 1;
    } else {
      output.push(prev);
      prev = curr;
    }
  }
  if (prev) {
    output.push(prev);
  }
  return output;
};

console.log(joinSlots(freeTimings));
```